# Flutter RouterDelegate: Android back button closes the whole app despite RootBackButtonDispatcher

Tags: android, flutter

I am using `PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin` and `RootBackButtonDispatcher` and I would expect that the back button press would call the `onPopPage` method of the navigator built in the router delegate. Instead the back button pops the whole app.

This is the app code

```
 GetMaterialApp(
            navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: Router(
              routerDelegate: AppRouterDelegate(),
              backButtonDispatcher: RootBackButtonDispatcher(),
            ),
```

and this is the RouterDelegate

```
class AppRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<AppRoutePath>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<AppRoutePath> {

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  AppRouterDelegate() : navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      pages: [
        if (!context.watch<AppState>().loadingDone)
          MaterialPage(child: LaunchWidget())
        else
          MaterialPage(child: AvailableMatches()),
        if (context.watch<AppState>().selectedMatch != null)
          MaterialPage(
              key: ValueKey("MatchDetails"),
              name: "MatchDetails",
              child: MatchDetails(matchId: context.read<AppState>().selectedMatch)
          )
      ],
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        print("popping");
        print(route.settings.name);

        if (!route.didPop(result)) {
           return false;
        }

        if (route.settings.name == "MatchDetails") {
          context.read<AppState>().setSelectedMatch(null);
        }

        notifyListeners();
        return true;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(AppRoutePath configuration) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should implement your custom BackButtonDispacher

```
class PageStackBackButtonDispatcher extends RootBackButtonDispatcher {
  final PageStack pageStack;

  PageStack get pageStackBloc => pageStack;

  PageStackBackButtonDispatcher(this.pageStack);

  @override
  Future<bool> invokeCallback(Future<bool> defaultValue) async {
    final result = pageStack.popYourPage();
    return result == BackPressedResult.keep;
  }
}
```